# Is the comma necessary in this sentence?

Tags: commas, sentence

Is the comma used in the following sentence necessary?

> Ellie said she couldn't wait for the vocabulary final, because
>   studying words is her favorite thing to do.

Thanks

Comment: The inclusion of the comma leads to the default meaning being 'The reason Ellie said "I can't wait for the vocabulary final" is that studying words is her favourite occupation.' Assuming 'Ellie said "I can't wait for the vocabulary final, because studying words is my favourite pastime" is intended, as seems likely, the comma is misleading (though I'd go further than dropping it, and rephrase).

Answer (score -1):

The coma does not need to be there.  The word "That" also needs to be in the sentence unless you are directly quoting.   Ellie said that . . .  Because  . . ..